Calculate distance from airplane to me using adsb
I use rtl-sdr dongle and dump1090 to get nearby airplanes. I get adsb SBS message. Now my question is that how can I calculate distance from an airplane and my rtl dongle?
In sbs message we have generation time and logged time. Is difference of this two value reception time or not? If is it true, can we calculate distance with this values? If yes, how?

Skimming through https://mode-s.org/decode/ I think the answer is "no." I don't think ADS-B messages include a timestamp. You can determine an aircraft's position using multilateration if you receive the same exact message at geographically distinct receivers; you can mark when each receiver got the message and work backward from there. But I don't think you can do it with just a single receiver.

Of course the ADS-B message also includes the aircraft's position (that's the entire point) and if you know your receiver's position, which you should, you can calculate the difference that way...

Thanks @randomhead, can I calculate my rtl dongle location using multilateration?

Not easily, if at all... but your receiver should be in a fixed location, generally speaking, right? And if it isn't, won't you be there with it and you can use a GPS device to report your current position? Or are you planning on sending your SDR dongle out on its own in a weather balloon or something? Also: there are USB GPS dongles that you can plug into your computer alongside the SDR.

no, I must find distance or my location without any GPS dongle in my project only with a rtl-sdr dongle. do you know any solution that you say is not easy?

@UKRock I think you're not barking up the right tree here. If you don't know where you are, you're going to have to figure that out first. There is no way to trilaterate unless you have ToF between at least two spatially separated receivers. And those receivers have to be time synced to nanosecond resolution. That's way, way, way more complex than having a GPS.

Regarding trying to use a a timestamp, the level of timing resolution AND time syncing you would need to calculate distance based on ToF (Time of Flight) is nanoseconds. That's just not reasonable, esp. since there is no mechanism for providing absolute timing on the ADSB side.
Instead, I would suggest just using google maps to figure out your personal lat-lon, and then use an online calculator to convert that to distance.
Formally, you want to use the haversine formula. 
In addition to the online calculator, https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html has all the equations you will need for a variety of solutions. It also has sample code, which might make it easy to automate the task.

Thanks for your answer, but I dont have my dongle location to calculate distance. Because my project does not have any user to check google map and calculate in online websites. Maybe if I ask how to calculate my location with sbs messages, is better!

@UKRock it's imperfect, but geolocation via IP address, e.g. https://www.iplocation.net/, can serve in a pinch.
